# Can i travel to Spain?

Tags: visas, spain, deportation

I was recently deported from the United States. I overstayed there without a visa for a long period of time, I was arrested last year and charged with 6 felonies but all my charges ended up getting dismissed & i was not convicted of anything, but due to my immigration status i was deported back to my home country. I would like to know if i am admissible to travel to Spain? I have a family member that lives in Barcelona and offered me to go stay with her. I have a Honduras passport and have read that it is not necessary to have a visa to travel to Spain for honduran citizens.

Comment: How feasible this is depends on what nation's passport you hold. Do you require a visa to enter Spain? Either way, unless you have a pending job offer in Spain, you cannot stay more than 90 days in any 180 day period.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to apply for a visa if you need one to enter the Schengen area. If you're asked about your immigration history, or the charges you faced (you might be asked if you were **charged** with any offences, in addition to whether you were convicted) you should reply honestly. I wouldn't rate your chances highly, but if you lie and are found out you can be sure of a refusal and probably a lengthy ban.

Comment: Unlike the UK for example, the Schengen visa application form does not ask about non-Schengen immigration history or criminal charges/offences http://www.exteriores.gob.es/ContenidoReutilizable/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Documents/visadoSchengen_EN.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As a Honduras citizen, you don't [need a visa](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/who-needs-schengen-visa/) to enter any country of the Schengen area, including Spain. You can stay for a max of 90 days, following the 90/180 rules.

The principal problem you might encounter is that, with a overstay in your historial, and being invited by a familiar to *stay with her*, the officer at the immigration interview might see you as likely to overstay again, and might deny you entry. To get a better chance of entering, you should bring evidence of strong ties to your country, a good financial situation, and a return ticket.

If, on the other hand, you're planning to stay longer, you'll have to get a [residence permit](http://www.interior.gob.es/web/servicios-al-ciudadano/extranjeria/regimen-general/residencia-temporal). For that, you need to show that you have no criminal records for 5 years in your previous countries of citizenship, but this shouldn't be a problem, as you were not actually convicted. Note that there are other requisites, and this might not be an easy path even if possible.

Finally, let me echo *user90371*'s comment: if you get asked about your immigration history, tell the officer the truth. Getting caught lying will probably lead to a ban, and many complications in the future.